# show that $kT_{\text{halftime}} = \ln 2$ with a differential equation

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

the following is the Newton’s Law of Cooling,

$$\frac{dT}{dt} = - k (T - T_a) $$
where $T(t)$ is the temperature of object at time $t$, $T_a$ is the ambient temperature at $23 ^\circ \text{C}$ and $k$ is a positive constant.

I took values from temp of $800 \text{ ml}$ of water cooling at ambient temperature of $23^\circ \text{C}$ from [here](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMAT6680Fa2014/Gieseking/Exploration%2012/Newton's%20Law%20of%20Cooling.htm)

I integrate it to get $T(t) = 23 + Ce^{-kt} $

To find arbitrary constant $C$, I substitute $t=0$, $T= 100$, and therefore I got $C= 77$

With that, I can find values of $k$. Since $k$ values are different at every time, I find $k$ values at $t=10,20,30$ and took the average which gives me $$k = 0.033474$$

The particular solution now is - $$T(t) = 23 + 77e^{-0.03347t} $$

I am trying to prove that $$ kT_{\text{halftime}} = \ln 2$$ where $T_{halftime}$ is the time taken for an object to cool to half of its initial temperature difference.

Initial temperature difference - $100-23 = 77$

Therefore Temperature when time is half of its initial temperature difference is $= 38.5$

Finding $t$ at $T=38.5$

$$15.5 = 77 e^{-0.033474t} $$

Therefore, $T_{\text{halftime}} = 47.886$

$$kT_{\text{halftime}} = \ln 2$$

$$0.033474 \cdot 47.886 = 1.602 \ne \ln 2$$

May I know where I have went wrong ? Thanks ..

Comment: Since you are using $t$ for time and $T$ for temperature, it is confusing to use $T_\text{halftime}$ to indicate time. Use $t_\text{halftime}$ instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by the $k$-values being different at every time. As mentioned in your link, $k$ is a *constant*. Moreover, it is a very precise constant, so approximating it is going to get in the way of what we need to do, in this case.

Also, you don't want the temperature to *be* half of the initial temperature difference. Rather, you want the temperature to *have cooled by* that amount, meaning the temperature in question will be $100-\frac{77}2.$ Consequently, your approximation of $T_{halftime}$ is not even close. Again, though, approximating it will only get in our way.

Fortunately, we aren't asked to demonstrate a value for either $k$ or $T_{halftime}.$ Instead, you should consider the equation $$100-\frac{77}2=23+77e^{-kT_{halftime}},$$ or equivalently, $$\frac{77}2=77e^{-kT_{halftime}}.$$ Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 1):

Denoting $t_{1/2}$ as halftime, and $T_{1/2}$ as temperature at halftime, where the temperature difference with ambient is half that at the start,, i.e. $\frac {T_{1/2}-T_a}{T_0-T_a}=\frac 12$,  we have:

$$\begin{align}
\frac {dT}{dt}&=-k(T-T_a)\\
\int_{T_0}^{T_{1//2}} \frac {dT}{T-T_a}&=-k\int_0^{t_{1/2}} dt\\
\bigg[\ln (T-T_a)\bigg]_{T_0}^{T_{1/2}}&=-kt_{1/2}\\
\ln\left(\frac {T_{1/2}-T_a}{T_0-T_a}\right)&=-kt_{1/2}\\
\ln\frac 12&=-kt_{1/2}\\
kt_{1/2}&=\ln 2
\end{align}$$